# Read a .Z file (unix compresses file) in Java

Tags: java, file, unix, compression

The said file extension is explained here at http://kb.iu.edu/data/abck.html. I want to use a java api to read the contents of a Z file. Neither the ZipFile api or the GZIPInputStream seem to work. I can use the ZipFile api to open normal .zip files.

```
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile("CR93H2.Z");
Enumeration entries = zf.entries();
```

To add, the said .Z file opens up fine in winrar.

Does anyone know about the solution to it.

Thanks

Comment: see [I need to extract .tar.Z file using java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15039566/309483)

Answer (score 1):

You can use compress-j2me:

```
% git clone https://github.com/igorgatis/compress-j2me.git
% cd compress-j2me/src/lzc-test
% ant -q
% cd build/cmd
% echo "testdonkeyballs" | compress | java com.googlecode.compress_j2me.lzc.Main -d
testdonkeyballs
```

For a maintained alternative, try [Apache Commons-Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/javadocs/api-release/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've had success reading compressed files with [UncompressInputStream.java](http://robotics.cs.columbia.edu/~mobility/docs/mob_pkg/JacORB/src/HTTPClient/UncompressInputStream.java).  I haven't verified if the logic is correct, but it seems to work.

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( new File( "thefile.cfg.Z" ) );
    InputStream is = new UncompressInputStream( new BufferedInputStream( fis ) ); 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is ) );
    String line = null;
    while ( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null )
    {
        System.out.println( "line = " + line );
    }
```