# I need to extract .tar.Z file using java

Tags: java, gzip, extract, unzip, zip

Do anyone have coding in java to extract .tar.Z files.

Assume that i am having file called home.tar.Z
I need extract this file using java code, can you give any sample code.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you fork a process doing that?

Comment: You can use [Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/index.html)

Comment: I tried with Commons Compress, it can't able to extract .Z files

Comment: see [Read a .Z file (unix compresses file) in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3473179/309483)

Answer (score 1):

The `.Z` extension is not the `gzip` extension, it is from `compress`.

You can launch shell scripts from Java, I'd do it like that, since I don't know any `compress` library for Java. For tar/gz you could use Plexus Archiver or Apache Commons VFS.

See

- [How do I extract a tar file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315618/how-do-i-extract-a-tar-file-in-java)
- [How to Compress/Decompress tar.gz files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128171/how-to-compress-decompress-tar-gz-files-in-java)

Sadly it doesn't seem that any libraries cover `.Z` files, so I think those links are unusable for you.

But take a look at:

- [How to make pipes work with Runtime.exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5928225/309483)

This allows you to do everything with the shell commands which means you won't have to bother doing it from Java.

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously late to help the OP, but for posterity, [Apache `commons-compress`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) does support *.Z.

For example

```
import org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.z.ZCompressorInputStream;

...

FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("/path/to/archive.something.Z");
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
ZCompressorInputStream zIn = new ZCompressorInputStream(in);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zIn));

while (null != (content = br.readLine())) {
  System.out.println(content);
}
br.close();
```